# Remove tags based on content using simple html dom

Tags: php, html, xpath, simple-html-dom

I'm trying to remove 2 html tags from a html variable by using a complex xpath query, however it does not seem to work. It does not remove anything. I guess this is due to the face that simple html dom does not fully support xpath and therefor the contains and parent functions does not work. I therefor wonder what i can do in order to achieve the same thing in simple html dom?

```
$gosu_full->find("//em[contains(., 'More content on GosuGamers:')]/parent::strong/parent::p/parent::div/following-sibling::div", 0)->outertext = '';
$gosu_full->find("//em[contains(., 'More content on GosuGamers:')]", 0)->outertext = '';
```

Comment: simple html dom does not fully support xpath

Comment: I can see that now, but what is my possibilities to achieve this anyway?

Comment: Use another parser. DomDocument for example